# Retrieving a shared preferences item from another activity. Android Studio, Kotlin, API 29

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I am a complete Novice writing my first app.
I created an Activity called SettingsInput.kt and it works fine saving settings as sharedPreferences, displaying them on press of buttons.

Now I want to use one of the settings as part of a calculation in a function to cull old data from a couple of tables in the database The function is in the databaseHandler class.

I get an error "Unresolved reference: getSharedPreferences" None of the methods I have tried have helped so far. Can anyone help, bearing in mind that the target API level is API 29?

```
 var sharedPrefFile = "greenbandbasicpreference"
val sharedPreferences:SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(sharedPrefFile,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)//doesnt recognise getSharedPreferences
fun cullData(){
    var noow = ZonedDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC())
    var noowSecs:Long  = noow.toEpochSecond()
    var noowMins:Long  = (noowSecs)/60
    //var bolusLifeMins:Long = 220// this has to come from a database or store of "preferences"
    //var bolusLifeMins:Long = sharedPreferences.getLong("insLife_key",0)
    val bolusLifeMins   = getSharedPreferences("greenbandbasicpreference",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    var minTimeMins = noowMins - bolusLifeMins - 2*(24*60)

    val db = this.writableDatabase

    db.delete(
        "BolusTable",
        "btime <"+ minTimeMins ,
        null
    )
    db.delete(//this is a part of the function for cull CarbsTable
        "CarbsTable",
        "carbTime <"+ minTimeMins ,
        null
    )


    db.close()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `getSharedPreferences` is a method from Context class, so you will need a context to request it, like:

```
context.getSharedPreferences(sharedPrefFile,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: Thank you @Bruno. Can you give me some direction as to what the context should be ? I have tried 1.  this,2.  the name of the class where the shared preferences file was declared(which is SettingsInput), 3.applicationContext . They all give me either the context as an unresolved reference, or getSharedPreferences as an unresolved reference

Comment: You said that this code is part of the databaseHandler, and a Handler is not a context. So, using "this" nor the class reference won't work, you may receive the context at the constructor. For instance, if your MainActivity is instantiating your handler, you can send the activity as the context itself.

Comment: Thanks again @Bruno. I moved the declaration of sharedPreferences up into the databaseHandler class, and added applicationContext thus "val sharedPreferences:SharedPreferences = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(sharedPrefFile,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)" then when I called sharedPreferences in the databaseHandler i added context exactly as you suggested like this "var sharedPrefFile = "greenbandbasicpreference"
    val sharedPreferences:SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(sharedPrefFile,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)" and it WORKS!!Can you explain the Bounty system?